Solve for the shape and curvature of Earth's magnetic field
How can I solve for the shape of Earth's magnetic field (neglecting the effects of the solar wind which distort it). It looks very similar to the field due to a solenoid, but I can only find solutions for the field inside a solenoid, and I want the field around the Earth. What I ultimately want to know is the angle of the field lines along the planet's surface (angle away from the normal to the planet's surface) as a function of longitude.

Wikipedia has the dipole approximation.

@Ghoster Thanks, it does have an expression for the field, but what I want to know is how to derive that expression.

The field outside a uniformly magnetized ball is a dipole field. See https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/lectures/node61.html for one derivation using the concept of scalar magnetic potential.

In the same way that the electric field outside a uniformly charged ball turns out to be the same as that of an imaginary point charge at the center, the magnetic field outside a uniformly magnetized ball turns out to be the same as that of an imaginary point magnetic dipole at the center.

Another derivation you could attempt is to integrate the fields from the actual infinitesimal magnetic dipoles in each infinitesimal volume element inside the ball. This is probably a difficult integral to evaluate analytically, but you could always do it numerically to convince yourself that the outside field is dipolar. Finite-sized magnets are just collections of point dipoles.

It's not something you solve. It's something you measure:
https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/world-magnetic-model
Last time I used it, briefly, it was only out to degree 7 (in contrast to gravity, which is available to degree ~2.5K or higher, depending on your access level).
Edit: So it's traditional with anything around a sphere to do a multipole expansion, which are the irreducible shapes that rotate nicely in spherical coordinates:

$l=0$, monopole = spherically symmetric

$l=1$, dipole = 3 vectors $\leftarrow$

$l=2$, quadrupole = 5 shapes with alignment $\leftrightarrow$ and no direction


...and so on...
Anyway, for uniform magnetized $\vec m$ sphere, that is pure dipole.
For a point $\vec r$ outside the sphere--really for a vector connecting the origin to the point, you can write down the form of the vector potential, $\vec A$:
$$ \vec A = c_1\vec m + c_2 \vec r + c_3(\vec m \times \vec r) $$
since those are the vectors in the problem.
Because $\vec A$ flips sign under parity and $\vec m$ does not:
$$ c_1 = 0$$
Because $\vec A$ flips sign under time reversal and $\vec r$ does not:
$$ c_2 = 0 $$
wile $\vec m \times \vec r$ has the same time/parity behavior as $\vec A$. I'll state w/o derivation:
$$ c_3 = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r^3} $$
so
$$ \vec A(\vec r) =  \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r^3} \vec m \times \vec r $$
whence:
$$ \vec B(\vec r) = \vec{\nabla} \times \vec A$$
$$ \vec B(\vec r)=  \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}
\Big[
\frac{3\vec r(\vec m \cdot \vec r)}{r^5} -
\frac{\vec m}{r^3}
\Big]
$$
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole)
At the surface, you can--a la Gauss's Law for gravity from a sphere--treat the magnetization as:
$$ \vec m(\vec r) = M\delta(\vec r) $$
Idk what $M$ is for the Earth, and if you want higher order moments: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion .

Thanks, fair enough, but there are definitely approximate expressions I've seen (for instance in @Ghoster's comment above) which is what I'd like to know how to derive.

@Random_Astro_Student Are you asking for a dipole (or higher) field out side and at the surface of the sphere of magnetized material? If that's it, I can update my answer.

Thank you! What is small vector m in your derivation?

the magnetic moment, or magnetization.
